# Some $\liminf$ for functions with same roots as $\zeta(s)$, in the critical strip

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, limsup-and-liminf, riemann-hypothesis

The function I have in mind is $f(s)=\phi(t)\cdot|\zeta(s)|$, where $s=\sigma + it$, $|\cdot|$ is the modulus, and $\frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1$ is fixed. Here $\phi(t)$ is a positive, increasing function of $t>0$, or possibly constant ($\phi(t)=1$). Let us denote as $L_\sigma$ the following quantity:

$$L_\sigma=\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} f(\sigma + it).$$

I can see the following *potential* scenarii:

- If $\phi(t)$ does not grow fast enough, say $\phi(t)=1$, then maybe
  $L_\sigma=0$. This would add some additional challenge to proving RH
  (the Riemann Hypothesis), yet this scenario by itself does not
  disprove RH.
- If $\phi(t)$ grows fast enough, say $\phi(t)=\exp(t)$, then maybe $L_\sigma>0$. Yet this scenario by itself does not prove RH. It would
  just simply be a much weaker result than RH.

I was wondering what are the most recent results concerning these types of $\liminf$.

Comment: Would the universality of the Riemann zeta function make $L_{\sigma} = 0$ for any choice of $\phi$? I might be mistaken.

Comment: I only checked for $\sigma=0.75$ and $0<t<10^4$.  While it seems $L_\sigma>0$ even with slow growing $\phi(t)=\sqrt{t}$, I am concerned that as $t\rightarrow\infty$, it might not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $1/2<\sigma < 1$ and $1\leq \phi(t)$ as a continuous function with your desired properties. Define $g_{\epsilon}$ as the polynomial approximation of $\epsilon*[\phi(\frac{1}{1-t})]^{-2}$ on the interval $[\sigma-i,\sigma+i]$. Since $\phi$ is increasing in $t$, we see that $g_\epsilon(1)=0$ for each $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Take $U$ to be the compact subset of $1/2<\sigma < 1$ containing our interval with no larger imaginary parts. We see that $f_\epsilon$ is analytic on the interior of $U$. Using [Universality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality) of the zeta function, we can arbitrarily approximate each $g_\epsilon$ by $\zeta$ on $U+it_{univ}$ for some $t_{univ}>0$ depending on said approximation. In fact, there are infinitely such $t_{univ}$ that can be selected to be arbitrarily large. We can then see that $$f(t)= \phi(t)*|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \approx \phi(t)*g_\epsilon(\sigma +i(t-t_{univ,\epsilon})) \approx \epsilon\phi(t)[\phi(\frac{1}{1-(t-t_{univ,\epsilon})})]^{-2}$$ Taking $t\rightarrow t_{univ,\epsilon}$, we see that $f$ can be arbitrarily small.

Sorry for a lot of missing details, but the universality of the zeta function in the critical strip should imply your limit infinum is zero for any choice of $\phi$.